# Is there any alternative to access event.target from a react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, dom

I'm creating a form and taking input from a mui textfield. I stored the value of the textfield to a value object. I created an onValueChanged function to store the key and value of the form fields. I want to show the current value in textfield and save it to the useState constant value. Is there any alternative method to achieve that? What is the basic structure of event.target?

It is giving an error that

```
 TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSQcy.png)

The snippet for the code is -

```js
const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    practiceSetName: "",
    grade: "",
    subject: "",
    level: "",
    correctMarks: "",
    topic1: "",
    topic2: "",
    topic3: "",
    incorrectMarks: "",
    timeLimit: "",
    exam: "",
    difficultyLevel: "",
    instructions: "",
    questions: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const [name, value] = event.target; //this line is giving error

    setValue(...value, ([name] = value));
    preferences = value;
    console.log("changed Data");
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value.questions);
    handleClose();
  };
```

```html
   <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      required
                      id="name"
                      label="Practise Set Name"
                      value={value.practiceSetName}
                      type="string"
                      fullWidth
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      required
                      id="grade"
                      value={value.grade}
                      label="Grade"
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="subject"
                      value={value.subject}
                      label="Subject"
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="topic1"
                      value={value.topic1}
                      label="Topic 1"
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="timeLimit"
                      value={value.timeLimit}
                      label="Time limit in minutes"
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="topic2"
                      label="Topic 2"
                      value={value.topic2}
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="topic3"
                      label="Topic 3"
                      value={value.topic3}
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      required
                      margin="dense"
                      id="level"
                      label="Difficulty level"
                      value={value.level}
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="exam"
                      label="Exam"
                      value={value.exam}
                      variant="standard"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="instructions"
                      label="Instructions"
                      value={value.instructions}
                      variant="standard"
                      multiline
                      fullWidth
                      maxRows={4}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="correctMarks"
                      label="Marks for correct answer"
                      variant="standard"
                      value={value.correctMarks}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                      autoFocus
                      margin="dense"
                      id="wrongMarks"
                      label="Marks for incorrect answer"
                      variant="standard"
                      value={value.incorrectMarks}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.target` is an object, to destructure the name and value use `{ name, value }`,
setting a new state is done though this way

```
setValue({
 ...value,
 [name]: value
})
```

So your final code should be something like this

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value: eventValue } = event.target; //this line is giving error
    // renamed to eventValue because value is already defined 
    // in useState
    setValue({ ...value, [name]: eventValue });
    preferences = value;
    console.log("changed Data");
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value.questions);
    handleClose();
  };
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer, I changed the destructuring as 
    const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setValue(...value, ([name]: value));
    preferences = value;
    console.log("changed Data");
    // console.log(value);
    console.log(value.questions);
  }; 
but even now the value in textField is not getting saved, it displayes an empty form when open and also console is not giving the inputs

Comment: The bug in this code is that every thing setValue() should  be inside an object as in the answer. setValue({ ...value, [name]: value })

Answer (score 0):

the error here i think is you are destructuring an object not an array

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target; //this line is giving error
  };

// when you are working with object {} when you are working with arrays []
```

```js
const arr = ["Maria","juan"]
const [firstName] //this will be "Maria"

const {name} = {name: "Maria"} // this will be maria
```